# Python Socket Server: Cant connect through internet

Tags: python, sockets

So Im building myself a small server application to beef up my resume but Im having an issue that I cant quite figure out

As far as I can tell my Server is running right, as I (on my own computer only) can connect to the server.

As soon as I try to get any other computer to connect to it, it never connects and Im at a loss and need ideas.

Im using google chrome to connect and Like I said before it works just fine but only on my computer

```
import sys
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created.')

host, port = socket.gethostname(), 30001

try:
    serversocket.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as msg:
    print('Binding failed, Error: ' + str(msg[0]) + '\nMessage: ' + msg[1])
    sys.exit()
print('Binding complete.')
print('Host name:\t ' + str(host) + '\nIP:\t\t ' + str(socket.gethostbyname(host)) + '\nPort: \t\t ' + str(port))

serversocket.listen(5)
print('Socket Listening...')

while True:
    socketConnection, addr = serversocket.accept()
    print('Connection established.')
    dataRecieved = socketConnection.recv(2048)
    print(dataRecieved)
    socketConnection.send("Sup Doooood")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket is bound to localhost, since you specified `host = socket.gethostname()`, and your host name is resolved to localhost. You'll have to bind the socket to `host = "0.0.0.0"` in order to make it reachable from any external host.

Change this line:

```
host, port = socket.gethostname(), 30001
```

to:

```
host, port = "0.0.0.0", 30001
```

Comment: Thank you it seems to be working, but incredibly slowly, any guesses as to why?

Comment: Nevermind it appears to be a hiccup, no idea why but its fine now, thanks again