# Python sockets cant connect to the server

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I cant connect to the server with client over the internet both on different windows machines. here is the server's side code:

```
import socket
def getPublicIP():
    import requests
    response = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org")
    return response.text
serverAddressPublic = getPublicIP()
print('serverAddressPublic:',serverAddressPublic)
serverAddressPrivate = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
serverAddressPrivate = "0.0.0.0"#also tried this
print('serverAddressPrivate:',serverAddressPrivate)
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverAddressPrivateAndPort = (serverAddressPrivate, 10001)
serverSocket.bind(serverAddressPrivateAndPort)
serverSocket.listen()
print(f"[LISTENING] server is listening on {serverAddressPublic}")
print(f"[LISTENING] server is listening on {serverAddressPrivate}")
clientSocket, clientAddress = serverSocket.accept()
print(f'connected to {(clientSocket, clientAddress)}')
```

for private IP for server I tried both `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` and `0.0.0.0` [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776405/11692124).

client's side code:

```
import socket
clientSocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverAddress='publicIPofServer'#uuu
print('before connected')#uuu
clientSocket.connect((serverAddress,10001))
print('after connected')#uuu
```

but it gives time out in the client: `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`.

so I tried `telnet publicIPofServer 10001` and `telnet privateIPofServer 10001` in cmd in server and both gave similar answer `Connecting To 0.0.0.0...Could not open connection to the host, on port 10001: Connect failed`

then I tried `netsh firewall set portopening TCP 10001 serverclientpythoncode` in cmd. even though I got `Command executed successfully`. but after `telnet 0.0.0.0 10001` got `Connecting To 0.0.0.0...Could not open connection to the host, on port 10001: Connect failed.`

### update

#### 1

with `netsh firewall set portopening TCP 10001 serverclientpythoncode` in 2 other computer, except my personal computer, I was able to make the connection. by on my pc, I couldnt do that. even by making new `inboundRule` in `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`. so how to open ports on my pc? note `netstat -an | find "LISTENING"` shows that its listening on `0.0.0.0:10001`.

#### 2

even with turning off the firewall completely I couldnt connect to my pc either through the client code or even pinging it!!! so I thought maybe the function is returning the IP wrong, but then I checked it from 5 other sites and it was right!!!1

Comment: Seems like a network issue. The code is working on my end and I can telnet to it on port 10001 using both my public and private IP addresses given that I have a properly configured port forwarding for the public IP

Comment: what should I do then, if it works on ur computer. I also have tried `netsh firewall set portopening TCP 10001 serverclientpythoncode` and also by making new inboundRule in `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about the network infrastructure ? It seems unlikely that the problem is on the client's end, so tell me about the server. It has a valid public IP address ? Were you able to access it before. What is the OS ? Can you for example successfully ping the IP of the server from the client, if so then you should look at server's firewall configuration.

Comment: u may want to reread the question. maybe u have missed some info due to edits.

Comment: Do you mean you are executing telnet from the server ? That should be working no matter of the network infrastructure. Make sure the server code is running and listening. then from the server execute 'telnet 127.0.0.1 10001'

Comment: now I made sure the server was running the tried `telnet 127.0.0.1 10001` and I went to an empty console

Comment: I cant ping or telnet with port from client to publicIpOfServer